# How do I adjust the inter footnote space in paragraphed footnotes in memoir class?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, memoir

I would like to reduce the space between paragraphed footnotes in memoir. Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\paragraphfootnotes
\begin{document}
\footnote{A footnote.}\footnote{How do I get this footnote closer to the previous one?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf):

> The mark is typeset in a box of width `\footmarkwidth` If this is negative, the mark is
>   outdented into the margin, if zero the mark is flush left, and when positive the mark is
>   indented. The mark is followed by the text of the footnote. Second and later lines of
>   the text are offset by the length `\footmarksep` from the end of the box. The first line of
>   a paragraph within a footnote is indented by `\footparindent`. The default values for
>   these lengths are:
>
> ```
> \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
> \setlength{\footmarksep}{-\footmarkwidth}
> \setlength{\footparindent}{1em}
> ```

Below I've adjusted `\footmarkwidth` to `.5em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\paragraphfootnotes
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{.5em}
\begin{document}
\footnote{A footnote.}\footnote{How do I get this footnote closer to the previous one?}
\end{document}
```

Note that the first footnote's numbering will extend into the left margin for too small a value for `\footmarkwidth`. One may have to tap into `\makefootmarkhook` if you want to do something special for using an even smaller `\footmarkwidth`.